# how to get only month and year value in sql from textbox with textmode property as month? asp.net c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

I am using `Textbox` with property `Textmode` month for year and month picker instead of date picker, how can I get the month value and year value from "2016-03" in sql?

I tried `MONTH('2016-03')` and  `YEAR('2016-03')` but it does not work.

[image: Image desc]

Comment: Can you be more specific what are you triying to achieve?, if you do `code` datefromparts(year,month,day) maybe

Answer (score 0):

Try this `MONTH('2016-03-01') and YEAR('2016-03-01')`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from participants where 
        year(registerdate) = 2016 
and     month(registerDate) = 1
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

The Question is tagged to `C#` also So This may also help you;

```
        string dateString="2016-03" // will be the input
        DateTime d;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out d))
        {
            string monthName = d.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // Will gives you the Month name
            int year = d.Year; // Will give you the year
        }
```

Comment: The question is also tagged to sql, hard to see which one the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of STR_TO_DATE(), YEAR() and MONTH() to achieve that.

```
mysql> SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('2016-03', '%Y-%m')), MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('2016-03', '%Y-%m'));
+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('2016-03', '%Y-%m')) | MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('2016-03', '%Y-%m')) |
+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|                                  2016 |                                      3 |
+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```